# Error when importing class to a module from directory at the same level as the module itself

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, import, module

I am trying to call a class B inside a module A. Class B calls a function c that returns a configuration object. The directory tree looks like this

```
parent_dir/
    |
    | -- moduleA/
    |      |
    |      | -- driver_script_A.py
    |
    | -- moduleB/
    |      |
    |      | -- class_B.py
    |      | -- function_c.py
    |      | -- driver_script_B.py
    |      | -- __init__.py
```

and the files I use look like this

```
### Class_B.py

from function_c import function_c
# other necessary imports here

....
....
....

class B:
    __init__(self, param, config=function_c())

    ### other class members here
```

```
## driver_script_A.py

import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import module_B
from module_B.class_B import class_B
```

Now, when I run `driver_script_A.py` it fails at line `from module_B.class_B import class_B` with an error

```bash
File "/abs/path/to/parent/dir/module_A/../module_B/class_B.py", line X, in <module>
    from function_c import function_c
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'function_c'
```

However, If run `driver_script_B.py`, `class_B` does the import of `function_c` and it works perfectly fine.

I would assume that since module A has imported class B, it would be able to find all dependencies of class B as well.

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, writing `driver_script_A.py` as this

```
## driver_script_A.py

import sys
sys.path.append('../moduleB')
from class_B import class_B
```

seems to work, but I'll be interested in seeing any better solution if there is one.